# What are the correct addresses for these subnets?

Tags: networking, ip-address, subnet

Assume that the 160.5.132.224/27 network is split into 2 subnets, with equal number of IP addresses. What are the correct addresses for these subnets

Basically, I am trying to find a fool proof method to calculate the network address for any subnet. The answer options are :
160.5.132.224/28

160.5.132.192/26

160.5.132.240/28

160.5.132.192/27

160.5.132.208/28

160.5.132.192/28

Can someone tell me which one is the correct one and demonstrate their working out.

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains it all.

Answer (score 0):

The specified address is a 32 bit number, and the subnet mask specifies the number of bits to hold constant in the subnet.  The notation `160.5.132.224/27` means to use the first 27 bits from the speicified address as the subnet and vary the last 5 bits as addresses in the subnet.

To split the subnet you would add a bit to the subnet, i.e. `/28`, and specify additional bits in the addresses by adding a `1` to one address and a `0` to the other.

In this case, the last eight bits in the specified address are provided by `224`, which is `11100000`.  You should change the last eight bits of one subnet to `11110000` (an extra one) which is `240`.  The other subnet will specify an extra zero, but it will remain `1110000` (which is still `224`).  Then you end up with  `160.5.132.224/28` and `160.5.132.240/28`.

Comment: So just to summarise, you add one to the subnet number (leading to /28), then you add 1 to the 28th bit for one subnet then add 0 to the 28th bit of another subnet?